# Switch between images as I move the Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of images:

```
<ul>
    <li id="angle1" class="first scroll-img1-wrap" style="display:block;">
         <img src="img/scroll/img1.png">
    </li>
    <li id="angle2" class="scroll-img2-wrap">
         <img src="img/scroll/img2.png">
    </li>
    <li id="angle3" class="scroll-img3-wrap">
         <img src="img/scroll/img3.png">
    </li>
    <li id="angle4" class="scroll-img4-wrap">
         <img src="img/scroll/img4.png">
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I have a jQuery standard slider.

I want to switch between my images as I move the slider:

```
$( ".slider" ).slider({
        animate: true,
        range: "min",
        value: 10,
        min: 10,
        max: 40,
        step: 10,

        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#slider-result" ).html( ui.value );
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {       
        }

    });
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use jQuery's .show() and .hide() functions, and use a standard class name (ex: scroll-img-wrap instead of scroll-img#-wrap).

http://jsfiddle.net/yFnwD/

If you have more than one of these sliders, than you may want to use a class on the UL tag, and then use descendent selector to find the child your after.

HTML

```
<div class="slider"></div>
<ul>
    <li id="angle1" class="scroll-img-wrap">
         ONE
    </li>
    <li id="angle2" class="scroll-img-wrap">
         TWO
    </li>
    <li id="angle3" class="scroll-img-wrap">
         THREE
    </li>
    <li id="angle4" class="scroll-img-wrap">
         FOUR
    </li>
</ul>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(".scroll-img-wrap").hide();
$(".scroll-img-wrap:first").show();
$( ".slider" ).slider({
        animate: true,
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: $(".scroll-img-wrap").length - 1,
        step: 1,

        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $(".scroll-img-wrap").hide();
            $(".scroll-img-wrap:eq("+ui.value+")").show();
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {       
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of what you can do with jQuery animate function. You can change the trigger according to your needs.

**http://jsfiddle.net/deKuf/4/**

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
  $("#angle1").mouseover(function(){
      $("#angle1").animate({height:"300px"});
  });
  $("#angle1").mouseleave(function(){
      $("#angle1").animate({height:"100px"});
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at their official demo (slider scrollbar) : http://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll
This will answer your question, you have to play on CSS property while you scroll.

Answer (score -1):

this could be solution (not tested):

```
<ul>
  <li id="angle1" class="first scroll-img1-wrap" style="display:block;">
     <img src="img/scroll/img1.png">
  </li>
  <li id="angle2" class="scroll-img2-wrap">
     <img src="img/scroll/img2.png">
  </li>
  <li id="angle3" class="scroll-img3-wrap">
     <img src="img/scroll/img3.png">
  </li>
  <li id="angle4" class="scroll-img4-wrap">
     <img src="img/scroll/img4.png">
  </li>
```

and javascript could be:

```
$( ".slider" ).slider({
    animate: true,
    range: "min",
    value: 10,
    min: 10,
    max: 40,
    step: 10,

    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        // get slider value and concatenates with image number and path
        // for case of zero change to 1, as your image starting from 1
        $("#mainImage").attr("src","img/scroll/img" + ui.value + ".png" );
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {       
    }

});
```

i hope it helps.